# hibernate ddl validation smallint vs int2

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, h2

I have a legacy application that I want to upgrade to JPA. For local development and testing I have configured an H2 in-memory database, on the test and production servers there is a PostgreSQL database, which defines the schema I want to map. I want to configure Hibernate to validate the DDL mapping (in Spring Boot with `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate`).

In the given PostgreSQL database the column type is `SMALLINT`, but the Java type of the corresponding attribute is `int`.

**And here comes the problem**: 
If I annotate the attribute with `@Column(columnDefinition="SMALLINT" ...)` then the validation with the H2 database is fine, with PostgreSQL however I see an error `found [int2 (Types#SMALLINT)], but expecting [smallint (Types#INTEGER)]`.

If I change the annotation to `@Column(columnDefinition="INT2" ...)` then PostgreSQL is happy, but H2 complains with `found [smallint (Types#SMALLINT)], but expecting [int2 (Types#INTEGER)]`.

So apparently the `Types` are different (`SMALLINT` in the database, but `INTEGER` in the Java code for the `int` attribute), so Hibernate uses the type name for comparing the types. But the same database type is reported by H2 as `SMALLINT` and by PostgreSQL as `INT2` (which is kind of strange, as pgAdmin displays the column also as `SMALLINT`).

Is there some way I can tell Hibernate or the JDBC drivers that these two type names should be treated the same?

PS: I found already some answers that advise using the `@Type` annotation, however (to make things even more complicated), the `int` attribute is contained in an `@Embedded` class which is from a library and which I cannot change, so I have to use `@AttributeOverrides` (which in turn doesn't allow `@Type`).

Comment: Use the same database in local development that you use in production, otherwise you will keep running into different issues.

Comment: Surely if it is an in-memory database then you want `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` when running on H2. You can use Spring profiles to enable multiple runtime configurations. H2 also has a Postgres compatibility mode. Don't know if that would fix your issues? http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility

Comment: Probably the proper pragmatic solution for now is to disable validation for H2.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the compatibility mode, @AlanHay (though it doesn't solve the problem)